# Is there a std::bytes?

Tags: c++, c++17

I like `std::byte`, but I dislike that it seems that it does not have its own container, since `std::vector<std::byte>` is quite verbose...
I know I could use using but for header files it is tricky since everybody using my code needs to use my alias and it is tricky for large projects that use many libraries to agree on one alias.

So does C++ standard or boost provide some nice `typedef` for vector of `std::byte`.

Comment: You can make your own: `using bytes = std::vector<std::byte>;`.

Comment: "*everybody using my code needs to use my alias*" Why should they? Maybe that's the problem you should be looking into: why you're passing around `vector<byte>` everywhere, instead of something less heavy-weight. Like a `gsl::span<byte>`, so that users aren't required to use `vector` just to talk to your code.

Comment: You could consider following the `STL` design model and provide an `API` using *beginning* and *ending* iterators rather than containers.

Comment: @NicolBolas - people also read source, not just compilers

Comment: @Galik no I do not intent to follow defective STL design that passes around begin and end.

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl: "*people also read source, not just compilers*". And if someone sees "`bytes`", they're probably going to want to know a bit more than "it's a thing that has bytes." Like, how does it store them? How can I access them? And so forth. `std::vector<std::byte>` tells the story; `bytes` does not. `std::array<std::byte, N>` tells a different story. Brevity is not always best when it comes to reading and understanding a piece of code.

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl: "*no I do not intent to follow defective STL design that passes around begin and end.*" Um, are you sure you want to use C++ then? Because that's kinda how we do things here. We even baked it into the language with range-based `for`. C++20 is going to have a ton of range facilities (including `span`).

Comment: @NicolBolas I know C++ way of doing things, it is just defective... Ranges will fix a lot of it...

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl Ranges are just an improvement on some aspects of `STL` design.. But STL philosophy was a revolutionary improvement in certain design problems allowing a very high degree of decoupling, along with a much safer approach to using pointers. Ranges are another logical step, but we would not have them without `STL` philosophy. And they are not entirely unproblematic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it does not.

Much of the time you are using bytes you won't want heap allocation in a buffer you don't control anyhow.